# Compute the integral over these paths

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to solve this integral problem, but, i don't know how to solve this.

Here is my problem :

$$\int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{1}{z-e^{i\pi/4}} \,\mathrm{d}z,$$

And, the curve is,

where,

$C(t) = t$, $t\in[0,1]$

$C(t) = 1 + (t-1)i$, $t \in [1,2)$,

$C(t) = 3 - t + i$, $t \in [2,3]$

$C(t) = i(4-t)$, $t \in [3,4]$

I know that I can't use the Cauchy-Gorsat Theorem for this because of the singularity. Also, I think that it will be complicated if I use the definition of line integral directly.

Please shed some light by giving me a Hint

Comment: None of these paths is closed, that's why you can't apply Cauchy-Goursat. The easiest way to evaluate the integrals is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @DanielFischer I assumed that it is one path $C:[0,4]\to \mathbb{C}$  so it is just the boundary of a square where one singularity is in the interior of the closed curve

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Ah, makes sense, considering the parameter intervals. It seems I was led astray by the plural in the title. Well, in that case, we have the good old integral formula as the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you already have the Residue-Theorem the answer will be very easy to get. But normally this can calculated by hand, as your curves are lines, if you have Cauchy Integral Theorem (saying that if you have a holomorphic function in a simply connected domain every integral along a closed path takes value zero) you can change the curve for some which you like more, but calculating the path integrals here is really easy, give it a try.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your saying "you can change the curve for some which you like more." I mean, Curve is already given. How can I change the curve?

Comment: @beak well then just ignore that part. Later in the lecture you will see that the line integral (for holomorphic functions) is not only well defined on the set of all curves but even on the quotient where you say that two curves are equivalent if they are homotopic. Just use the definition of line integral

Comment: So, should I use the definition of line integral? Namely, $$\int_{\mathcal{C}} f(c(t))c'(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: @baek yeah and split it up in the four paths you already gave us. The integral you get is always of the form $\int \frac{1}{t+c} \, \mathrm{d}t$ if you factor out some constants and this shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Okay, let me give just 10-15min. After then, I will post it on this page.

Comment: Like you said, for four paths, I could make the form of integral of 1/t+c dt. And I remember that the integral of 1/t+c is  just ln|t+c| + C, C is constant. But, I'm not sure whether I'm in right track or not.

Comment: I can't get the line integral when t $\in$ [1,2) and t $\in$ [2,3)

Comment: @beak why? what is different there`?